# How to block a Url using c++ qt application

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a QT application with webkit browser with below feature:

1. By default, google website (http://google.com) is displayed to user and it must allow access to all the url except google hangout.

I created below program which will open the google url but don't know how to block the desired url:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebkitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QUrl>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setup(this);
  ui.webView->load(QUrl("http://google.com"));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Based on earlier version of the question, you probably want to override this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#acceptNavigationRequest

Comment: But really, your question makes no sense to somebody who doesn't know the context. Add details, and try to think from the point of view of others here reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

I´m going to make this a brief answer. Qt provides a number of great examples with the installation, you should look at the Tutorial examples for the Webview one, it´s a QML application -- and it is really easy to modify it to your needs.

As the navigation bar is a separate element, which is separately scripted, you can make it callback to C++ where you can apply a filter to it. The example you should look for is called ´quicknanobrowser´.

**Edit**
To clarify, based on a comment, you can also act on the signal when a new page is loaded. This would be placed inside BrowserWindow.qml, ctrl+f for "onNewViewRequest", which is another signal that is acted upon in the same manner:

```
onLoadingChanged: {
    if(loadRequest.url == "www.blockedurl.com")
    {
        // Do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the user searches for google hangouts and clicks on a link? As I understand the question all access should be blocked, not just entering the url.

Comment: I tried to use above mentioned code but I am unable to use the functionality, while building the project it throws no module with QWebView. The current installed QT version is 5.7.0.

Comment: @Unknown that may be an installation issue. You may have to change your installation to include QML and webkit